# How to hit external graphql URL using gql

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

How to hit external graphql URL using [gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql)?

As per github repo:

```
from gql import gql, Client

client = Client(schema=schema)
query = gql('''
{
  hello
}
'''
)
```

client.execute(query)

Even though, the author say it is inspired by [apollo client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client) ,I didn't see any way of providing URL while executing the graphql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client [accepts](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql/blob/master/gql/client.py#L18) an optional `transport` parameter, on which you can give an instance of `gql.transport.requests.RequestsHTTPTransport`.

Its first parameter is the URL:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
transport = RequestsHTTPTransport("http://example.com")
client = Client(schema=schema, transport=transport)
query = gql('''
{
  hello
}
'''
)
```